Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext' when use .net and postgreSQL
I got this error when I try to "Add-Migration" to PostgreSQL in .Net:
This is code in Program.cs:
using expenseTracker.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

//DI
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(
        //Host=localhost;Database=TransactionDB;Username=postgres;Password=admin
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")
    )
);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();

This is the code of ApplicationDbContext:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace expenseTracker.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
        {}
        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}

Here is the error:
Add-Migration "Initial Create"
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'.
For the different patterns supported at design time, see
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728


It should be  "DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>"
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options)
        {}


I tried. But still not work.

@RachelDuan Besides, builder.Services.AddDbContext should be added before builder is built  var app = builder.Build();, it could be the issue.
